# Rails eager_load deep associations on an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below are my five models and relevant associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end    

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :super_category
end

class SuperCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories
end
```

Next I find a `User` object:

```
@user = User.find(1234)
```

Now what I want to do is I want to eager_load the following:

- All of the User's `Answers`

  - Each of the Answers' associated `question`

    - Each of the questions' associated `sub_category`

      - Each of the sub_categories' associated `super_category`

I attempted the following:

```
@user.eager_load(answers: {question: {sub_category: :super_category}})
```

However it comes back with the following error:

> NoMethodError ... Undefined method 'eager_load' for the [user record]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Question:** how do I eager_load the associations above on the instance?

I am not sure if this matters or not: but at the time that all the eager_loading is conducted: none of the associated `question` records have been persisted, so all of their `ids` are nil.  I don't think this matters, but just in case: I figured I should mention it.

Comment: `User.eager_load(answers: {question: {sub_category: :super_category}}).where("users.id = ?",1).first` or `User.eager_load(answers: {question: {sub_category: :super_category}}).find(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to prevent N+1 query.

Preload performs individual SQL queries for each collection.

Eager load construct one left-joined SELECT to retrieve all collections in one query.
If you use `includes` Rails pick which one to use.

eager_load is a class method. You should use on the model Class.

Try like this:

```
User.eager_load(answers: {question: {sub_category: :super_category}}).where("users.id = ?",1).first
```

or

```
User.eager_load(answers: {question: {sub_category: :super_category}}).find(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Awlad suggests in his comment, `eager_load` should be called on the class, not the instance. See the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-eager_load). Nice work, Awlad!

Comment: how do I eager_load on an instance?

Comment: See Awlad's answer. I think he has you covered.

Answer (score 0):

For an instance, its worth trying `preload`...[Take a look at the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader)

Assuming,

```
#share is polymorphic
#share is created by user

share ||= shared.tap do |share|
  ::ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(share, [:user, :shareable])
end
```

Or, using `includes`

```
Share.includes(:user, :shareable).find(share.id)
```